# Unlimited input without using array

Tags: java, input

Hi I am trying to write a java program that accepts as many input from a user and output the maximum, minumum and the mean value without using an array.

- **This is the instruction:

Write a program LoopStatistics that reads values on the console and outputs some statistical
quantities of the entered set of numbers afterwards. If no positive number is entered, the program
prints no number entered.
Assignment
The user can enter as many positive floating-point numbers on the console as desired. Zero (or a
negative numbers) signals end of input (no more numbers can be entered). After input the program
displays
 the smallest number entered (min)
 the largest number entered (max)
 the mean of all numbers entered (mean)**

```
public class LoopStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch;
        int n=0;
        TextIO.putln("enter numbers:");
        for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){
            n = ch;
            n =TextIO.getInt();
            while (n>0){
                ch++;
            }
            break;
        }
        TextIO.put(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop only gets executed once. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Your question is not clear. What do you need those char's for? 'while' piece should give infinite loop. The program has seemingly NOTHING to do with the statement in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate average with user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887498/calculate-average-with-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

Don't store all user entries, just keep a minimum, maximum, running total and number of entries.

Comment: Hmmmm. Steenslag, i think you just gave me an idea on what to do

Comment: This is the new code I came up with. but its not working the way I would like it to work. with the min max. it not executing well

Comment: @Michael Don't change your question - it makes the answers useless for later readers. Just pose a new question.

Comment: Ok. sorry about that. this is my first time posting here

Answer (score 0):

lets analyse your code here :

```
    for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++){

        n = ch;                // the value of n is now equal to the value of ch
        n =TextIO.getInt();    // now the value of n is changed to the value received by the TextIO.getInt()
        while (n>0){           
            ch++;
        }
        break;                // your loop stops here in it's first iteration
    }
    TextIO.put(n);
```

a simple question here, what is the use of the variable "ch" in this piece of code !?

now if you just want to check if the user input is less than or equal to zero, why not use a simple if statement for that in your loop, if it is true, break, else continue !?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Now your problem is that you're setting a bunch of variables you don't need to. Honestly, your problem isn't a programming one, it's a basic logic one.

You can't combine your "minimum" check with your "maximum" check. Instead you want something like

```
int numbersEntered = 0;
double minimumNumber = 0;
double maximumNumber = 0;

while(userIsEnteringNumbers) {
    if(numberEntered < minimumNumber) {
        minimumNumber = numberEntered;
    }

    if(numberEntered > maximumNumber) {
        maximumNumber = numberEntered;
    }

    ++numbersEntered;
}
```

---

There's a few things here that don't make sense, but I'm assuming that by "without using an array" this includes things like Sets

In that case, you don't want to store user input, just the lowest value, highest value and the number of values the user has entered. Calculate the mean after the user has finished entering values.

In terms of your loop, you want to either loop a number of times the user chooses (in which case get this information before the loop and then initialise your for loop with it) or you want to loop indefinitely until the user enters a specific value (for example a new line or anything that isn't a number).

Now on to the problems in the code you've submitted..

```
for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
```

Why are you using letters to loop round? You don't appear to be using anything that requires letters, so just use numbers to keep things simple. You can initialise variables in your for loop, like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
```

Try to avoid re-using variables, it will make your code difficult to read.

```
n = ch;
n =TextIO.getInt();
```

You assign n the value of ch, and then immediately afterwards you assign it the value of TextIO.getInt(). The statement 'n = ch' might as well not be there. If you are wanting to perform some kind of operation on it, use **+=, -=, *=** or **/=**.

```
while (n>0){
        ch++;
    }
```

That is essentially either an infinite loop or a loop that will never be reached, depending on the value of n. The only variable you are incrementing there is ch, which means that n will ALWAYS be greater than 0 and your code will never go any further

Try implementing the solution I suggested at the start of my answer and if you're still stuck, post back

Comment: Please i have just updated my code. If you could take a look at it please. The max and min is not executing well

Comment: @Michael. I have updated my answer to account for your edit. I'm not sure how much more I can tell you without giving you the solution which, as you a) asked me not to in the original post and b) your question appears to be homework, would be a bad thing to do